# TFS Build Workflow InvokeProcess PsExec

Tags: tfs, build-process, build-automation, psexec, automated-deployment

I am trying to run a batch file automatically during a build from a TFS build workflow.  I have added an InvokeProcess activity with  the following:

```
    Arguments: "\\" + agent + " /accepteula -u username -p password -d C:\HelloWorld.bat"
    FileName: "PsExec.exe"
    OutputEncoding: System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)
    WorkingDirectory: "C:\PSTools"
```

I have ensured that both the build agent and the build controller have access to the "agent" in question.  I have also ensured the PsExec.exe is located in the "C:\PSTools" folder as defined.

When executing the build I get the error "File not found: PsExec.exe"  Does anyone have any idea what would cause this error in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with FileName: "C:\PSTools\PsExec.exe"

Comment: Actually this worked like a charm... originally I thought it didnt but I tried running the build again and apparently the changes to the workflow had not saved correctly.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: You responded faster than I could edit my comment, this was the correct answer I am not sure why though since I thought the Working directory was supposed to point to the directory that the "FileName" is contained in.

Comment: happy to answer your question Aaron and unlock your problem